# Apache DigestUtils seem to calculate MD5 partially wrong

Tags: java, hash, md5

tonight I was working on an easy solution for an on-the-fly-MD5 calculation while a stream is passed. The main framework was working perfectly straight away. The data got streamed and the MD5-hash computed. But then I started monitoring the MD5-Hash at 3 different stages. Before streaming, while streaming and after streaming. And I was suprised by the result.

The most important MD5-digest was obviously wrongly computed. For all encoding I used the same method of Apache's DigestUtils. But instead of generating 3 times the same output, I got only 2 of 3.

To verify, that there is no general error in my construct I additionally used Apache's `(...).binary.Hex` class to encode the digest. And this time the result matched with the other ones.

MD5 before streaming: 9065793b048f4efee5ccddb34798ee19

MD5 after streaming: 9065793b048f4efee5ccddb34798ee19

MD5 while streaming encoded by DigestUtils: **95d845ff55b5918edc8d1222045dd1cb**

MD5 while streaming encoded by binary.Hex: 9065793b048f4efee5ccddb34798ee19

And here is my very simple code.

The first class is started via the main method.
It calls an instance of the class StreamForwarder and passes the test string
as InputStream. That's it.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;

public class StreamProvider {
    private static final byte[] streamContent;

    static {
        streamContent = "i9BjYXhrIA7FvuQ8WTIhIbgCGwfIGKfu".getBytes();
    }

    private static InputStream getStreamContent() {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(streamContent);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("MD5 before streaming: " + 
            DigestUtils.md5Hex(streamContent));

        StreamForwarder streamForwarder = new StreamForwarder();
        streamForwarder.forwardStream(getStreamContent());
    }
}
```

The StreamForwarder wrapps the InputStream in a DigestInputStream and gets an instance of the MessageDigest to compute the MD5-hash while streaming.
It calls an instance of the class StreamConsumer and passes the DigestInputStream.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.DigestInputStream;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;

public class StreamForwarder {

    public void forwardStream(InputStream is) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        DigestInputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(is, md);

        StreamConsumer streamConsumer = new StreamConsumer();
        streamConsumer.printStreamContent(dis);

        byte digest[] = md.digest();

        String digestUtilsHexString = DigestUtils.md5Hex(digest);
        String binaryHexString = new String(Hex.encodeHex(digest));

        System.out.println("MD5 while streaming encoded by DigestUtils: " + 
            digestUtilsHexString);
        System.out.println("MD5 while streaming encoded by binary.Hex: " + 
            binaryHexString);
    }
}
```

Finally the StreamConsumer reads the stream using Apache's IOUtils.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class StreamConsumer {

    public void printStreamContent(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        String myString = IOUtils.toString(is, "UTF-8");

        System.out.println("MD5 after streaming: " + 
            DigestUtils.md5Hex(myString.getBytes()));
    }
}
```

As you can see there is no rocket science behind it. But still the output of the StreamForwarder.class is not what I was expecting concerning the encoded HexString of DigestUtils.

Has anybody an explanation for me why this happens? Have I done something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in this line

```
String digestUtilsHexString = DigestUtils.md5Hex(digest);
```

You are occasionaly calculating digest of a digest - *md5hex(md5(is))*. You may check it in bash

```
$ echo -n 9065793b048f4efee5ccddb34798ee19 \
    | perl -pe 's/([0-9a-f]{2})/chr hex $1/gie' \
    | md5sum
95d845ff55b5918edc8d1222045dd1cb  -
```